# Unable to read sibling and child of the sibling from XML file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I wanted to read PMID and author forename from the xml file, sample file shown below

I am getting the PMID and forename but the loop as the number of times of PMID, I want 1 PMID and there respective forename

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PubmedArticleSet SYSTEM "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/ncbi/pubmed/out/pubmed_190101.dtd">
<PubmedArticleSet>
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">2844048</PMID>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Guarner</LastName>
                <ForeName>J</ForeName>
                <Initials>J</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Cohen</LastName>
                <ForeName>C</ForeName>
                <Initials>C</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Mushi</LastName>
                <ForeName>E</ForeName>
                <Initials>F</Initials>
            </Author>
        </AuthorList>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
<PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
        <PMID Version="1">123456</PMID>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Smith</LastName>
                <ForeName>C</ForeName>
                <Initials>C</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Jones</LastName>
                <ForeName>E</ForeName>
                <Initials>F</Initials>
            </Author>
        </AuthorList>
    </MedlineCitation>
</PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

code, I have tried

```
FN=[]
for pmid in root.iter('PMID'):
    print(pmid.text)
    for id in root.findall("./PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/AuthorList"):
        for f in id.findall("./Author/ForeName"):
            fn=f.text

            x= '{},{}'.format(i, fn)
            #print(x)
            FN.append(x)
```

expected output

```
PMID               AUTHORS
2844048            'Guarner J J', 'Cohen C C'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want the output to be in a specific format. However, you can try the following code. The output is a Dictionary where Keys are the PMID and Values are the list of Authors.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
tree = ET.parse('E:\Python\DataFiles\PMID.xml') # change according to your location
authors_pmid = []
all_authors_pmid = []
root = tree.getroot()
for amedlinecitation in root.iter('MedlineCitation'): #PMID and Author are childs of MedlineCitation
    pmid = amedlinecitation.find('PMID').text
    for anauthor in amedlinecitation.iter('Author'): # for each amedlinecitation, find all its Authors
        author_name = anauthor.find('LastName').text # for each Author, find the LastName tag and extract its value
        authors_pmid = [pmid,author_name]
        all_authors_pmid.append(authors_pmid)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_authors_pmid,columns=['PMID','Author'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
{'2844048': ['Guarner', 'Cohen', 'Mushi'], '123456': ['Smith', 'Jones']}
```

Following code will give the output in Tabular form using Python Dataframe.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
tree = ET.parse('E:\Python\DataFiles\PMID.xml') # change according to your location
authors_pmid = []
all_authors_pmid = []
root = tree.getroot()
for amedlinecitation in root.iter('MedlineCitation'): #PMID and Author are childs of MedlineCitation
    pmid = amedlinecitation.find('PMID').text
    for anauthor in amedlinecitation.iter('Author'): # for each amedlinecitation, find all its Authors
        author_name = anauthor.find('LastName').text # for each Author, find the LastName tag and extract its value
        authors_pmid = [pmid,author_name]
        all_authors_pmid.append(authors_pmid)
df = pd.DataFrame(all_authors_pmid,columns=['PMID','Author'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      PMID   Author
0  2844048  Guarner
1  2844048    Cohen
2  2844048    Mushi
3   123456    Smith
4   123456    Jones
```

How the above code is different than the first code:

1. For each pair of PMID and Author name, it will create a list. This list is named authors_pmid. For example, ['2844048', 'Guarner'], ['2844048', 'Cohen'], ['2844048', 'Mushi'], ['123456', 'Smith'], ['123456', 'Jones'] will be the values in list variable authors_pmid during each iteration of the inner for loop.
2. Then each of the above lists will be appended to final list define by all_authors_pmid
3. This final list will be the data input to the call to Dataframe constructor to create a Dataframe with columns names as: PMID and Author

Comment: Thanks a lot, {'2844048': ['Guarner', 'Cohen', 'Mushi'], Can I get input like 2844048' Guarner'           '2844048':Cohen  2844048:Mushi?

Comment: While running the code on entire file, I am getting the error, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', getting author_name = anauthor.find('ForeName').text

Comment: Do you want the output in the form of a dictionary like {2844048:'Guarner', 2844048:'Cohen', 2844048:'Mushi'}? This is not possible because Dictionary have unique keys. So, the key 2844048 can appear only once in the dictionary and it will have the last entered value. Any values written before will be overwritten by the new value. If you want multiple values belong to one Key, then make a list of those values and assign it to the Key. This is what my code above does.

Comment: Regarding the error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', getting author_name = anauthor.find('ForeName').text", it is difficult to for me to comment without knowing what code you are running.

Comment: i solved the attribute error, no I want input in dataframe like in one row 2844048' Guarner', in 2nd row 2844048:'Mushi. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it can be done using PythonDataframe. I have edited my answer above. Please check the second approach.